# How to transform only one table column into responsive

Tags: html-table, responsive-design, css-tables

I have a table with 3 columns (used to display an album songs). Number, Track Title and Artist. I wanted to keep the column of Number and Artist small, and allow Title to place most of the space of the column. And I wanted to make it responsive for mobile.

I managed to make it right with `white-space: nowrap`, `overflow: auto`, and adding a `max-width` in the table td. This looks nice in a Desktop with a large display, but it seems that in mobile screens the `width:100%` used in the `table` does not apply, because the table overflows the limit of the screen.

How can I fix it and display the full table in small screens? Is it only possible with `@media`?

The work done is here:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

table th {
  background: #E4E4E4;
  line-height: 23px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  color: #626262;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 11px;
  border: 1px solid #DBDBDB;
}

table td {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 22px;
  background: #F7F7F7;
  border-top: 1px solid #F3F3F3;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 300px;
}

table td,
table th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 3px 20px;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Nº</th>
      <th class="largura-min">Title</th>
      <th>Artist</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>I need this column placing most of this space / Superlong String Superlong String Superlong String Superlong String Superlong String Superlong String Superlong String Superlong String Superlong String Superlong String</td>
      <td>ARTIST</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>TITLE 2</td>
      <td>I NEED A SMALLER ARTIST SPACE / SUPERLONG ARTIST SUPERLONG ARTIST SUPERLONG ARTIST SUPERLONG ARTIST SUPERLONG ARTIST SUPERLONG ARTIST</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say that width:100% is ignored, do you mean that the table's width becomes larger than the screen width and a horizontal scrollbar appears?

Give each column a different max-width in px units, in the same proportion of space you want them to take up. I removed a bunch of stuff from your example just to make experimenting easier. Resize the output frame on https://jsfiddle.net/dgrogan/ye2wm4yp/2/

But note that Firefox doesn't seem to support overflow:auto on table cells. If you need to support FF you'll have to figure that out. Didn't test Edge.

Grid might support this use case better than tables.

```js
let reducer = (sum, current) => sum += current;

let cells = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("tr:first-child td"));
let abs_widths = cells.map(cell => cell.offsetWidth);
let total_width = abs_widths.reduce(reducer);
let pct_widths = abs_widths.map(w => Math.round(1000 * w / total_width) / 1000);
let specified_widths_px = cells.map(cell => parseInt(getComputedStyle(cell).maxWidth));
let total_spec_widths = specified_widths_px.reduce(reducer);
let specified_widths_pct = specified_widths_px.map(px => Math.round(1000 * px / total_spec_widths) / 1000);
log.innerHTML = `${abs_widths}
<br>${pct_widths} <-- current column ratio
<br>${specified_widths_pct} <-- specified column ratio
`;
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

table td {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 22px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-right: 0px;
  outline: 1px solid lime;
}

td:nth-child(1) {
  max-width: 10px;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  max-width: 50px;
}

td:nth-child(3) {
  max-width: 35px;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Nº</td>
    <td class="largura-min">Title</td>
    <td>Artist</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>I need this column placing most of this space / Superlong String Superlong String Superlong String Superlong String Superlong String Superlong String Superlong String Superlong String Superlong String Superlong String</td>
    <td>ARTIST</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>TITLE 2</td>
    <td>I NEED A SMALLER ARTIST SPACE / SUPERLONG ARTIST SUPERLONG ARTIST SUPERLONG ARTIST SUPERLONG ARTIST SUPERLONG ARTIST SUPERLONG ARTIST</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id=log></div>
```